# OpenCV Installing (make) errors on /modules/objdetect/

Tags: opencv, make

im a total noob to raspberry and I want to create an opencv gesture recognizing app with the pi camera (the one which is connected thru the socket next to the hdmi port) and was installing opencv 3.1.0 thru terminal, and started building it with the make command, but after 12 hours I got an error and it just halted.

First question is: How can I fix the error? (See terminal output below)

And next one is, do I have to restart the whole process and wait 13 hours in order to see if it works or not?

Heres the terminal output at the moment of the error:

```
    Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_objdetect
[ 45%] Building CXX object modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_objdetect.dir/test/test_cascadeandhog.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_objdetect.dir/test/opencl/test_hogdetector.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_objdetect.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_objdetect
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_objdetect.dir/build.make:160: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_objdetect' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_objdetect] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6616: recipe for target 'modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_objdetect.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/objdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_objdetect.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I am a relative newcomer to raspberry PI and opencv, i came across this website pyimagesearch.com it has lots of posts on installing and using opencv, it may help with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem had to do with Disc Space issues... Seems like a file on the sd card got corrupted. Bought a new sd card and installed everything from scratch again, and this time it worked. Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need OpenCV as it is designed to be used over GPU.

You can use instead NumPy.

In order to recognize gestures you will need to use convolutional networks for wich you will need SIMD(Single Instruction Multiple Data) hardware componenets.

Comment: I would, but I need it to be with openCV.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing openFrameworks, it includes openCV. There is a tutorial [here](https://openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/raspberry-pi-getting-started)

Make sure you run :

- `apt-get clean`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Wouldnt it take much longer since it includes a lot of other stuff?

Comment: It gets the job done. I use openframeworks beacuse I could not get the regular install working, and because I was going to use the things OpenFrameworks installs for me anyways. It is not a perfect solution, but it is A solution.